# Web Api Passing extra "default" parameters as mandatory input

Tags: controller, webapi, .net-6.0

I have a Controller with multiple methods. each method has a unique Input model and diffrent Http method (GET/POST/Etc ...) . I would like to have the ability to support multiple default properties that repeat in few methods.

Repeated model that needed to be input by default to all Input Models Example:

```
string TrackingId;
string TrackingTime;
```

I know i can use OOP, to wrap each InputModel, But is it possible to use **Api controller** library or **specific Attribute** to describe an attached model to each request?

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, the only reasonable solution was to wrap input models with Specific class with the default requirements.

```
public class DefaultParams{
    public string trackingParam {get; set;}
}
public class InputModelA : DefaultParams {
    public string a {get; set;}
    public string b {get; set;}
}
```

another good solution was to use **HttpContext** and look for specific values within a custom Attribute implementation. this method wasn't easy to implement and i end up not using it.